# Динамические веб страницы на чистом c# без php/phyton/.net razer

Tags: c#, веб-сервер

Данный подход не парсит html как php, razer, а генерирует разметку на лету.
Что сказывается очень хорошо на производительности.
Имеет ли такой подход место быть. Ведь если писать все в таком, по мне так удобном стиле, на сколько я понимаю можно улететь в StackOverflow

Код страницы

```
    public AdminLoginPageWrong()
    {
        Add(
            new HeadTag
            {
                new MetaTag(new NameAtt("description"), new ContentAtt("Вход в админ панель")),
                new MetaTag(new NameAtt("author"), new ContentAtt("Alay")),
                new MetaTag(new NameAtt("viewport"), new ContentAtt("width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")),
                new TitleTag{new Svt("Вход в админ панель") },
                //new BaseTag(new HrefAtt("http://localhost:8080/"))
            },
            new BodyTag(new ClassAtt("gray-bg"))
            {
                new DivTag(new ClassAtt("middle-box text-center loginscreen animated fadeInDown"))
                {
                    new DivTag
                    {
                        new DivTag().Add(new H2Tag(new ClassAtt("logo-name")).Add(new Svt("WGS")))
                    },
                    new H3Tag().Add(new Svt("Добро пожаловать на форму авторизации администратора WGS")),
                    new PTag
                    {
                        new Svt("WGS - Лучшая CMS полностью написаная на C# без использования .net asp."),
                        new BrTag(),
                        new Svt("Скорость реакции в десятки раз превосходит остальные веб серверы и сам asp"),
                    },
                    new PTag().Add(new Svt("Авторизуйтесь, чтобы пороникнуться возможностями WGS")),
                    new DivTag(new ClassAtt("alert alert-danger"))
                    {
                        new Svt("Пользователь или пароль не верны.")
                    },
                    new FormTag(new ClassAtt("m-t"), new RoleAtt(RoleAtt.Mark.Form), new MethodAtt(MethodAtt.Mark.Post), new ActionAtt("adminAuth"))
                    {
                        new DivTag(_classFormGroup)
                        {
                            new InputTag(new NameAtt("login"), new InputTypeAtt(InputTypeAtt.Mark.Email), _classFormControl, new PlaceHolderAtt("Login"), new RequiredAtt())
                        },
                        new DivTag(_classFormGroup)
                        {
                            new InputTag(new NameAtt("pass"), new InputTypeAtt(InputTypeAtt.Mark.Password), _classFormControl, new PlaceHolderAtt("Pwd"), new RequiredAtt())
                        },
                        new ButtonTag(new InputTypeAtt(InputTypeAtt.Mark.Submit), new ClassAtt("btn btn-primary block full-width m-b")).Add(new Svt("Вход"))
                    },
                    new PTag(new ClassAtt("m-t")).Add(new SmalTag().Add(new Svt("WGS - World Global Sharper based on Bootstrap 3 and .net framework 4.6.1 © 2017")))
                },
                new LinkTag(new RelAtt("stylesheet"), new HrefAtt("admin/css/bootstrap.min.css")),
                new LinkTag(new RelAtt("stylesheet"), new HrefAtt("admin/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css")),
                new LinkTag(new RelAtt("stylesheet"), new HrefAtt("admin/css/animate.css")),
                new LinkTag(new RelAtt("stylesheet"), new HrefAtt("admin/css/style.css")),
                new ScriptTag(new SrcAtt("admin/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")),
                new ScriptTag(new SrcAtt("admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"), new AsyncAtt())
            }
        );
        Render(null);
    }
```

Код абстрактного тега

```
    private bool _isRendered;
    private string _data;
    private readonly string _name;

    private readonly List<AbstractAtt> _attributes;
    private readonly List<IHtmlRendable> _innerTags;

    private readonly bool _needToBeClosed;
    private readonly bool _hasAttributes;
    private bool _hasInnerTags;

    public delegate IHtmlRendable[] EntryFunc();

    protected AbstractTag(string name, bool needToBeClosed, params AbstractAtt[] attributes)
    {
        _name = name;
        _needToBeClosed = needToBeClosed;
        _attributes = new List<AbstractAtt>(attributes);
        _innerTags = new List<IHtmlRendable>();
        if (attributes.Length > 0) _hasAttributes = true;
    }

    public IHtmlRendable Add(params IHtmlRendable[] tags)
    {
        if (!_needToBeClosed) return this;//Если тег не закрывающийся, то и контент в него добавить нельзя.
        _innerTags.AddRange(tags);
        _hasInnerTags = true;
        return this;
    }

    public IHtmlRendable Add(EntryFunc func)
    {
        if (!_needToBeClosed) return this;//Если тег не закрывающийся, то и контент в него добавить нельзя.
        _innerTags.AddRange(func());
        _hasInnerTags = true;
        return this;
    }

    public void Render(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        if (!_isRendered)
        {
            var enterPoint = sb.Length;
            sb.Append("<").Append(_name);
            if (_hasAttributes)
            {
                sb.Append(" ");
                foreach (var att in _attributes)
                {
                    att.Render(sb);
                    sb.Append(" ");
                }
                sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); //Удаляем последний пробел
            }
            if (!_needToBeClosed && !_hasInnerTags)
            {
                sb.Append("/>");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(">");
                foreach (var tag in _innerTags) tag.Render(sb);
                sb.Append("</").Append(_name).Append(">");
            }
            var exitPoint = sb.Length;
            var length = exitPoint - enterPoint;
            _data = sb.ToString(enterPoint, length);
            _isRendered = true;
        }
        else sb.Append(_data);
    }

    public IEnumerator<IHtmlRendable> GetEnumerator() => _innerTags.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _innerTags.GetEnumerator();
```

Абстрактный атрибут

```
    protected AbstractAtt(string name, string value)
    {
        _name = name;
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = true;
    }

    protected AbstractAtt(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void Render(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        if (_hasValue)
            sb.Append(_name).Append("=\"").Append(_value).Append("\"");
        else
            sb.Append(_name);
    }
```

Ну и все это дело превращается в [image: Html rendered]

Comment: А вы не ищете легких путей :)

Comment: Что бы получить overflow,  нужно 1. узнать размер вашего стека. 2. узнать рамер данных которые вы хотите поместить в стек. Скорее всего вы врядли его так просто переполните, разве что у вас будет более 1000 обьектов на один вызов. Стек считается примерно по колличеству аргументов в одной процедуре, где ссылка на обьект=4 или 8 байт.

Comment: Переполнение стека може быть вызвано 1. закцикленной рекурсией (тут этого нету). 2. Если вы вглубину (в даном примере в ширину) вызываете несколько процедур/функций у которых большой обьём параметров (или в качестве параметра используются структуры без ссылки/указателя) или аналогичных локальных переменных. Незнаю прокатит ли такое с с# поскольку при вызове функции зараннее известен нужный размер стека, и VM может позволить себе взять ещё места под стек, т.е. 1-2 Gb. На эти цифры вы не выйдите.

Comment: У меня рекурсию x86 на 50000 int пропускает. на 100 000 нет, это говорит о том что у вас должно быть более 50 000 параметров c стековыми переменными и прочими потрохами, что б вызвать Stackoverflow.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы. Буду и дальше разрабатывать в таком направлении.

Comment: В программировании скорее всего так - всё что не запрещено - разрешено. Так можно делать. А на счёт производительности - это ещё спорный вопрос что будет быстрее работать - данный код, или распарсить aspx (вы же код парсера aspx не видели ещё). Я думаю данный код отработает быстрее. Используйте профайлер, или сами замеряйте время выполнения - тогда получите более менее значимые результаты/ответы.

Comment: Интересный подход, но такое решение будет крайне тяжело поддерживать, когда проект разрастется

Comment: Похоже на микрооптимизацию без замеров производительности. Уверен, что тот же Razor генерирует более производительный код, и с меньшем потреблением памяти и нагрузкой на GC.

Comment: Невозможно генерировать "более" производительный код (хотя то что он генерит, это не код, а всего лишь разметка), если ты парсиш html. У меня же никакого парсинга нет, есть только "рендер", если его так можно назвать, но посути все го лишь указания для StringBuilder какие символы добавлять в буффер.